# AWS Lambda Layers - How to export all shared object file dependencies as docker layers

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile, amazon-linux, aws-lambda-layers

My end goal is to execute a [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) binary on a Lambda. This was possible with older versions of node lambdas (v8) however in the newer versions some shared objects are no longer available on the execution environments. I am able to create and upload lambda layers with the follower Dockerfile

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-provided

RUN yum install -y make sqlite-devel build-essential libsqlite3-dev zlib1g-dev bash git gcc-c++

# Create a build directory; clone tippecanoe; and copy in all files
RUN mkdir -p /build
RUN git clone https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe.git /build/tippecanoe --depth 1

# Install system dependencies
WORKDIR /build/tippecanoe

# Build tippecanoe
RUN make && make install

# Copy binaries to `/opt`
RUN cp ./tippecanoe /opt/tippecanoe
RUN cp ./tile-join /opt/tile-join
```

With this I can execute the following node.js lambda

```
export const handler = async (event: SQSEvent): Promise<any> => {
  await executeTippeCanoe();
};

async function executeTippeCanoe() {
  try {
      const { stdout, stderr } = await asyncExec('/opt/tippecanoe --version');
      console.log('stdout:', stdout);
      console.log('stderr:', stderr);
  } catch (err: any) {
     console.error(err);
  };
};
```

It creates the tippecanoe binary correctly but it depends on some shared objects and results in `error while loading shared libraries: libsqlite3.so.0`.

Though much trial and error I found that if I was able to locate libsqlite3.so.0 and place it in a `/lib/` directory in the layer it would work but just result in more missing shared objects. I am wondering how I can use Docker to export all of these shared dependencies installed via `yum` into a Docker layer.

Comment: Why not deploy the lambda using container image?